# How to import modules into Jupyter notebook

Tags: python-2.7, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

So I am using anaconda and conda in a Windows OS.

And as you may know Jupyter gets installed automatically with Anaconda.
My python code runs normally when using the python command

```
python myfile.py
```

However when I try to run it through jupyter I receive the following error

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-43605f892034> in <module>()
      1 #!/usr/bin/env python
      2 import os
----> 3 from gensim import corpora, models, similarities
      4 from gensim.models import LsiModel
      5 import logging

ImportError: No module named gensim
```

To troubleshoot I checked the following

1. Made sure to run jupyter notebook while enabling the activating the proper environment
2. Made sure the activated envrioment has the "gensim package" installed

Comment: Jupyter may be launching the kernel in a different environment from the one it runs in. Check the 'Kernel -> Change kernel' menu to see if you can easily switch it. `sys.executable` should show you which copy of Python the kernel is running in.

Comment: @ThomasK I double checked .. I am running the correct kernel .. sys.executable prints 'C:\\Program Files\\Anaconda2\\python.exe' which I believe is the right python copy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to solve this issue I need to install the missing library through jupyter itself

So I have to add and run the following command in a jupyter cell

```
pip install --upgrade gensim
```

Comment: This is riduculous, it doesn't work like that at all with all other libraries. You can install any other library in the command line and it will work in jupyter without this workaround